# Ember breaks due to Prototype.js

Tags: ember.js

I am embedding my Ember App into another environment. Prototype.js is in use there. Due to this, ember breaks.

I have read http://emberjs.com/guides/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/

```
I followed that but unfortunately issue is not resolved.
```

JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/raqab/2/edit

```
I am not sure what i am doing wrong here, Can anyone please assist me?
```

Answer (score 0):

In the same guide, where the effect of disabling prototype extensions is explained for [arrays](http://emberjs.com/guides/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/#toc_arrays), it is said that

> Native arrays will no longer implement the functionality needed to observe them. If you disable prototype extension and attempt to use native arrays with things like a template's {{#each}} helper, Ember.js will have no way to detect changes to the array and the template will not update as the underlying array changes.
>
> Additionally, if you try to set the model of an Ember.ArrayController to a plain native array, it will raise an exception since it no longer implements the Ember.Array interface.
>
> You can manually coerce a native array into an array that implements the required interfaces using the convenience method Ember.A:

Therefore change your `model` hook as

```
App.ApplicationRoute=Ember.Route.extend({
  model:function(){
    return Ember.A(["one","two","three"]);
  }
});
```

and in your template,

```
<ul>
 {{#each model}}
   <li>{{this}}</li>
 {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Updated jsbin: http://jsbin.com/hayata/1/edit

Now no error is thrown by ember, but some error is thrown from your other scripts.

Once you fix that it'll be all ok.

Comment: You are right. i have read about Arrays and forget to use Ember Array instead of using native Array. But you could see exception in console as 'Uncaught RangeError: Invalid array length' occurs in ember.js.